# Adding/Subtracting days from a date doesn't change the year/month correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

If I have a date that is `2011-01-02` and I subtract `7` days from that date it should give me `2010-12-26`, but instead it gives me `2011-01-26`?

See the JS below to verify with link:

```
var date = new Date('2011','01','02');
alert('the original date is '+date);
var newdate = new Date(date);
newdate = newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7);
var nd = new Date(newdate);
alert('the new date is '+nd);
```

http://jsbin.com/upeyu/6

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you meant to do this: (working perfectly)

```
var date = new Date('2011','01','02');
alert('the original date is '+date);
var newdate = new Date(date);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7);
var nd = new Date(newdate);
alert('the new date is '+nd);
```

#### jsFiddle example

Comment: the year should be 2010, and the month should be december.

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment by accident :( +1, this works because Javascript knows how to deal with negative dates - February the -5th

Comment: Actually I think I am confused.  Isn't 2011-01-02 = Jan. 2, 2011.  Why is it Feb 2, 2011?

Comment: Javascript months are zero-indexed: 0 = January. Go figure!

Comment: I just needed the actual number date from the calendar, so this is what I ended up doing... http://jsfiddle.net/dennismonsewicz/ghqhP/

Comment: the problem is when the number is in a var than you have to use ... newdate.setDate(newddate.getDate() - parseInt(mynumber));

Answer (score 4):

`getDate()` and `setDate()` both refer to only the day of the month part of the date. In order to subtract `7` days you want to do this:

```
myDate.setDate( myDate.getDate() - 7 );
```

This sets the day of the month to the day of the month minus seven. If you end up using a negative number it goes back to the previous month.

Answer (score 2):

.getDate() only returns the day of the month, and .setDate() only sets the DAY of the month, not the date.

Try doing

```
var date = new Date('2011','01','02');
alert('the original date is '+date);
var newdate = new Date(date.getTime() - 604800000);
alert('the new date is '+newdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) method is only *supposed* to set the day of the month

Comment: Ohhh.  Thanks.  Do you know what method I need to use to make it work correctly for months and years?

Comment: You can perform date arithmetic by adding/subtracting numbers of milliseconds, so `new Date(date - (7 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) // 7 days ago`. It's clunky, yes, but it's the only native way

Comment: Sorry, this answer might be correct but it doesn't fully answer the question because Javascript is smarter than I make it sound - see Jacob Relkin's answer

Comment: @Gareth Strange. When I use setDate() and getDate() and minus number of days, the month is also subtracted by 1 even though the month should remain same say July 15 - 5 => June 10. But using the native way works as it should !

Answer (score 0):

i have written a utility program
                Date.prototype.subDuration = subDuration;
                function subDuration(a,b) {
                    if ((typeof a === 'string')&&(typeof b === 'number')){
                       if ((a ==="Add") || (a ==="Sub")){
                         subdur.call(this,a,b)
                       }else{
                         return false;
                      }
                    }

```
                function subdur(action,days){
                   switch (action){
                      case 'Add': 
                      addDays.call(this,days);
                      break;
                      case 'Sub': 
                      rmvDays.call(this,days)
                      break;
                      default:
                      return false;
                   }
                   function addDays(days){
                        this.setDate(this.getDate()+days)
                   };
                   function rmvDays(days){
                        this.setDate(this.getDate()-days);
                   };
                }


            }

            var d = new Date('2011','00','02');
            alert(d);
            d.subDuration('Add',2);
            alert(d);
            d.subDuration('Sub',3);
            alert(d);
```